# Step 6 Installing Canonical’s OpenStack Autopilot

Tags: maas, openstack, openstack-autopilot

I'm at step 6 of the ez mode OpenStack instructions from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-openstack-with-autopilot and I'm unclear as to which box to actually run the "openstack-install" command on.  As I read the instructions it sounds like I install OpenStack on my freshly minted MAAS box but from the network diagrams it looks like you have a MAAS controller sitting on the side and an OpenStack controller sitting next to it.

Shoud I:

- Run "openstack-install" on the MAAS machine?
- Push an Ubuntu install to the machine I want as my OpenStack controller and run "openstack-install" on that one?

Thanks for any help! I think I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you could do either.  However, depending on the size of your intended cloud, running MAAS separately from where you run openstack-install might make sense.  Most deployments I would expect you to run openstack-install on your MAAS server, infact, the instructions intend on you doing exactly that.

The first step of the installer is to install Landscape to one of the nodes listed in MAAS.  After that process is done and some services are deployed, then you'll load up Landscape to actual deploy openstack to the remaining nodes.  Then the services like Neutron, Compute, Cinder, etc, etc... Will be spread over the network.

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  I appreciate the "why" background, that was what I was looking for.